# Measuring the execution time of python scripts

Tags: python, time, timeit

I am currently working on an ML NLP project and I want to measure the execution time of certain parts and also potentially predict how long the execution will take. For example, I want to measure the ML training process (including sub-processes like the data preprocessing part). I have been looking online and I have come across different python modules that can measure the execution time of functions (like the time or timeit ones). However, I still haven't found a concrete solution to predict the time it will take for a function to execute. I have thought about running the code several times, save the (data_size, time) values and then use that to extrapolate for future data. I also thought about then updating this estimation with the time it took the run several subparts of a function (like seeing how much of the process was computed, how long it took and then use that to adjust the time left).

However, I am not sure of any of this and I wanted to see if there were better options out there that I wasn't aware of, so if anyone has a better idea, I'd be thankful if you could share it.

Comment: Your main goal is to_predict_ how long functions will take to run? Or you want simply to measure them?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: @Josh Both. But my main question would be how to predict since I think measuring how long certain functions take to run would be easy using ones of the modules I mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using profiling? It should give a detailed breakdown of the function execution times, the number of calls, etc. You will have to execute the script with profiling, and then you will get the detailed breakdown. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile

If you want in-time progress reports there are a couple of libraries I've seen. https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/
https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/

Hope these help!